# Greasemonkey script, call functions from other page script

Tags: jquery, greasemonkey

the page for which I am writing a greasemonkey script already includes jquery, so I would like to know if/how I can access the jquery functions already included rather than including jquery in my greasemonkey script.

in my attempts, the jquery works fine if I include it in my script. but I'm not finding functions that were included by the server page.  I have no control of the server.

mostly just curious if I can access those functions.

worst case scenario I'll include jquery code in my script, so it's not a serious problem.

Comment: Why was this question downvoted?  It looks like a perfectly clear question to me.

Comment: What are `functions that were included by the server page`?

Comment: $() and several others  http://www.craigslist.org/js/jquery.js

Comment: Looks like they are accessible through unsafeWindow.

Is there a more secure way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit hacky, but sometimes you can trigger functions on the page by creating an triggerfunction HTML element and insert it into the page. Then use Greasemonkey to click on the link when you want to trigger the function.

For example, imagine that there's a function on the page called "runGame()". Early in your Greasemonkey script you have:

```
 var triggerHTML = "<a id=\"triggerfunction\" onclick=\"runGame()\">triggerfunction</a>";
```

And you insert it into the page at a suitable point. For example, imagine that you've found a place in front of which it could sit nicely:

```
 target.parentNode.insertBefore(triggerHTML, target);
```

And then later when you want to run the function, you execute

```
 var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
 evt.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
            false, false, false, false, 
            0, null);
 var triggerGame= document.getElementById("triggerfunction");
 triggerGame.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

Comment: Where is `runGame()` defined?

Comment: It's an example of a function that might be included in the Javascript of the page loaded (for example, between some script tags), but for which there is no HTML interface element that you can click on to run it. My answer shows how you can use Greasemonkey to add such an element, and then "click" on it programmatically to trigger the function. You can replace "runGame()" with whatever function it is in the page that you want to run.

Answer (score 0):

You should call the page scripts using `unsafeWindow`, e.g. instead of `$` you would write `unsafeWindow.$`.

BUT make sure you understand the safety threats arising from using unsafeWindow - they are decribed at http://wiki.greasespot.net/UnsafeWindow .